# echo values and add together inside a loop to make a total

Tags: php

I originally needed the array sum of x amount [trip_price] to be added together from a single booking in the system. Here was a single booking that consisted of 2 types of sums inside the same booking.

The total amount was taking `$booking_total = $post_metas['fcb_booking_total'][0];` which in turn was producing a static number, so when changes were made to a booking the price never updated.

```
$get_price = $wpdb->get_results("select trip_price from fcb_booking where order_id = " . $order_id . " order by start_date_time asc");

print_r($get_price);

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [trip_price] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [trip_price] => 5000
        )

)
```

EDIT.

From the answers below I used this. This made updates change the price to the new price for a user etc. This is needed ti be shown in email confirmations.

```
$get_price = $wpdb->get_results("select trip_price from fcb_booking where order_id = " . $order_id . " order by start_date_time asc");
$booking_total = 0;
foreach($get_price as $key => $value) {
    $booking_total += $value->trip_price;
};
```

From there I used this to return the price if the user paid 100% or 50% option on the site, any admin discount and a 5% additional fee

```
$total = $booking_total + $extra_total;
$total = $total * 1.05;


if($need_to_pay){
    if($amounttopay == 50){
        $total = $total / 2;
    }
}

if($admin_discount>0){
    $total = $total - $admin_discount;
}

return $total;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use loop `foreach` to echo and sum valuse:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($get_price as $price) {
    echo "price =" . $price->trip_price . "\n";
    $sum += $price->trip_price;
}

echo "Total sum=" . $sum;
```

Comment: Please check the code. Parse error there.

Comment: I corrected code @Pupil

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Try This code:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($get_price as $key => $value) {
    $total += $value->trip_price;
}

echo $total;
```

Comment: this looks like what i was trying to achieve on my own. But failed :)

Answer (score 2):

**You may use [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) in php**

array_sum — Calculate the sum of values in an array

```
$arr = ["trip_price" => 1, "trip_price" => 5000];
$sum = array_sum($arr);
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if array is not empty.

Use PHP's [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function for that.

If we do not add a check for this, we will end up in error.

Loop over array.

Take a variable for saving total.

Add sum in each iteration.

```
$get_price = $wpdb->get_results("select trip_price from fcb_booking where order_id = " . $order_id . " order by start_date_time asc");
$total = 0;
if (! empty($get_price)) {
 foreach($get_price as $key => $value) {
  $total += $value->trip_price;
 }
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: nice answer and comments, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your goal is to print out each element and/or calculate the sum.

There are several ways to achieve that:

1. **Full SQL**: rely on SQL engine to calculate the sum

   ```
   $totalAmount = $wpdb->get_results("
       SELECT SUM(trip_price) AS total_amount
       FROM fcb_booking
       WHERE order_id = " . $order_id . " ORDER BY start_date_time ASC");
   ```

   In that case you cannot really display each element you're adding up.
2. **Loop in Php**

   ```
   $prices = $wpdb->get_results("
       SELECT trip_price
       FROM fcb_booking
       WHERE order_id = " . $order_id . "
       ORDER BY start_date_time ASC");

   // Array map gives $arr = [0, 5000];
   $arr = array_map(function ($el) {
       return $el->trip_price;
   }, $prices);

   // Adding up prices: 0 + 5000 = 5000
   $sum = array_sum($arr);

   var_dump($sum);
   // => int(5000)
   ```

   If you want to print each price out, just add an `echo $el` in the callable of `array_map`.